# dangerouslySetInnerHTML and <Link>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gettext

My page requires localization. I use gettext. My `i18n.__` function returns translated string and replaces `%s` symbols with provided arguments.

As far as I know, I can't *'dangerously set'* a JSX element, however I need to insert opening and closing `<Link>` tags. 
I can't split the string into multiple pieces because back-end provides me such.

I am open to any ideas.

Here's my `div` element:

```
<div                                
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: i18n.__('Feel free to %scontact us%s if you have found a bug.', ['<Link to="/info">', '</Link>']) }}
/>
```

Comment: What are you trying to wrap in the `<Link>` tags?

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda I need `Feel free to %scontact us%s if you have found a bug.` to become `Feel free to <Link to="/info">contact us</Link> if you have found a bug.`

Comment: @RudolphTheCat Did you found a solution?

Comment: @Thore It's been a while. I posted my solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I found is that You use an `<a>` tag instead of a `<Link>` tag and fiddle with `onClick` event on the whole wrapper. It goes something like this:

```
<div
    onClick={(e) => {
        this.navigate(e);
    }}
>
    ...
    <div                                
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: i18n.__('Feel free to %scontact us%s if you have found a bug.', ['<a href="/info">', '</a>']) }}
    />
    ...
</div>
```

And the `navigate` function checks if you have clicked on the `<a>` tag and prevents the redirect by `event.preventDefault()`. Then the history is "pushed":

```
navigate(event) {
    const siteUrl = "https://www.test.com";
    if (event.target.tagName === 'A') {
        const href = event.target.getAttribute('href');
        if (href.indexOf('mailto:') === -1) {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.props.history.push(href.replace(siteUrl, ''));
        }
    }
}
```