# Insert Link with React variable statements (JSX)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

If we have to insert normal html elements with React Variables in JSX, it is easy, We can use  [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266197/reactjs-convert-to-html), or we can use any npm packahe [html-react-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser).

Below code works fine.

```
const thisIsMyCopy = '<p>copy copy copy <strong>strong copy</strong></p>';
render: function() {
    return (
        <div className="content" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: thisIsMyCopy}}></div>
    );
}
```

But If we try to add any Link element inside the html, It do not convert into anchor tag.

```
const thisIsMyCopy = '<Link to="/button" >button</Link>';
```

If we inspect this element, this does not shows as anchor tag,  Below is the Sandbox example for this.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-example-y5m94?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark 
I hope, many of you react developer must have

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48025373/dangerouslysetinnerhtml-and-link

Comment: Did you import link?

Comment: yes.  @shai_sharakanski I tried by imported Link as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to make it not string:

```
const thisIsNotWorking = <Link to="/button" >button</Link>;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const thisIsMyCopy = '<Link to="/button" >button</Link>';
```

Here this "thisIsMyCopy" is not a regular HTML element because of which when you try to insert a non HTML element or something random into the DOM, the DOM does not understand this element.check [Document Type Definition (DTD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_definition), The DTD specifies which element types are possible (i.e. it defines the set of element types) and also the valid combinations in which they may appear in a document
    If you'll replace it by

```
const thisIsMyCopy = '<a to="/button" >button</a>';
```

It will work because  is a valid HTML element.

2)From your statement it looks like, thisIsMyCopy is actually a React Router Link component. so in order to render a custom Component you can always render it as a child. 
  The purpose of dangerouslySetInnerHTML is to set some valid HTML.